# ValueError: The passed save_path is not a valid checkpoint: /content/gdrive/My Drive\model\20191003053122/variables/variables

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

Ran the code

```
export_path= '/content/gdrive/My Drive'+ '\\model\\'+'20191003053122'

with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, ["myTag"], export_path)         
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
```

and incurred error

```
ValueError: The passed save_path is not a valid checkpoint: /content/gdrive/My Drive\model\20191003053122/variables/variables
```

What I don't understand is that I have set the same path previously(`export_path = '/content/gdrive/My Drive' +'\\model\\'+time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S",time.localtime())`
) but Google Colab still says the checkpoint not valid. What does it mean and went wrong? I also changed both paths multiple times(like replacing `'/content/gdrive/My Drive'` with `os.getcwd()+`) to make sure they match each other but didn't help.

I am wondering if it's because the code

```
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, ["myTag"], export_path)         
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
```

is deprecated- if that's the case, what equivalent should I use instead? Maybe `Keras`? Any contribution is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is an access issue between Google Colab and Google drive

Can you take a step back and verify whether your Google drive is mounted properly and you are able to write and read files via Goole Colab.?

Here are the steps to be followed:

1. Import and mount Google Drive

   ```
   from google.colab import drive
   drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
   ```
2. Verify you are able to list the files in your drive or the location you want to write into

   ```
   !ls "/content/gdrive/My Drive"
   ```
3. Write the file in Google Drive,

   I have used `"w"` so that it creates the file if it doesn't exist

   [Other file modes in Python `open()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

   ```
   with open("/content/gdrive/My Drive/myFile.txt", "w") as file:
   file.write("Your text goes here")
   ```
4. Read the file again to check if the writing file went well!

   ```
   !cat "/content/gdrive/My Drive/myFile.txt"
   ```

[Image of my Google colab working code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kQaW.png)

[You can even check the official Goolge Colab notebook with steps here](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=XDg9OBaYqRMd)

Hope this helps :)